# How can I calculate exact duration for test run in Azure DevOps? I do not want to have test run pause time in duration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, duration, testcase, azure-devops-extensions

I want to calculate the test run duration. I see the start time and duration in Azure DevOps but it is included also the pause time. test run was 5 minutes and rest was pause time but it shows the duration 16 minutes!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0QfQ.png)

I tried REST API call but I got the same result! I expect to have approximate time estimation for each test run.

Comment: Dose the test run always last 16minutes in every execution? And what's the test type? How about the local test duration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.